# Is it possible to hookup two ultrasonic sensors to one Arduino Uno unit?

Tags: arduino-uno

I found a couple of projects using Ultrasonic Distance sensor with Arduino Uno. Is there a way to connect two or more sensors on the same Arduino Uno?

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried? What have you had problems with?

Comment: Please help us help you by providing your code showing your efforts.

Comment: Well I actually I did not try it yet it's just that I had worries that it might not by feasible so I did not buy any hardware and made the bad decision to ask a question here without trying anything :)

Comment: It is possible. Just ping then one after another, or both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible.  There are a few things you need to be aware of:

1)  The Arduino UNO is 5V by design.  Many sensors (not all, but many) are 3.3V devices.  So connecting them to a 5V pin could damage them.  Since you seem to be just starting out, I'd recommend sticking with 5V tolerant sensors.

2)  The Arduino UNO only has so many pins available....obviously.  Different sensors require different amount of pins to 'work'.  For example, a temperature sensor might work with the SPI interface.  Another sensor might require 8 pins.  So if you start running out of pins, you need to think about other challenges like using shift registers, multiplexers, etc.

3)  Don't be afraid to experiment.  I suggest buying a genuine Arduino UNO to support the project.  Maybe buy some cheap Chinese ones to experiment on...in case you fry on of those.

In theory, the sky's the limit when it comes to "how many".  In real life, if you start going over a handful, dozen, etc. then you might want to rethink your design.

Comment: You make some useful general points, but Stack Exchange is really about specifics - a specific question, and an answer which specifically addresses it.  Very little of what you have said applies to the actual question asked.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you have a point but I guess my question was also too broad

Comment: @ChrisStratton people come to Stack Exchange via searching or directly.  Looking for answers.  Sometimes the questions are broad like this one Sometimes they are very specific.  It seems that every day I see more and more examples of people scolding new users, beginners and amateurs.  Many times S.E. is the first response to a Google search.  Yet, when beginners ask, they are told to "Google it" and get down-voted and closed.  I understand that S.E. is about specific questions.  This question seemed specific enough for me. Google brings people here and they are punished, where should they go?

Comment: The problem isn't so much the question, as that you didn't answer it.  Very little in your response is even applicable to the actual question, vs some other ones not asked.

Comment: I guess I read the question as "is it possible".  My mistake.  But I still stand by my remarks.  Point is, many people come to S.E. looking for generic answers to their generic questions and, apparently, S.E. isn't a place for that.